# remove query string for static content in DNN platform

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke

query string for static content adds more size to link and pages. i have checked `gtmetrix` test for my site performance . one of problem that reduce site speed is add query string to static file url . it seems that cache work better with these strings. are they really needed ? how it is possible to remove them from static files.

Answer (score 0):

Which querystrings for static content? You mean "/portals/_default/default.css`?cdv=148`"? If you do then the answer is no. Though I doubt removing them will have much impact on performance.

But you can reduce the number of static files by combining CSS and javascript files into composite files, thus reducing the number of files send to the browser by the server. You can find it under "Host Settings > Advanced Settings > Client Resource Management"

Comment: `sharbatezaferan.png?ver=1395-03-25-085706-133` adds to end of url . Css file has been combined . but images and other file cant

Comment: In which module does this happen? I don't recognize that versioning.